# Parametrization of a completed projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to parametrized the completed projective of the curve $V(X^2+Y^2-2X)$. The completed projective is
$$V(F)=\{(X_0:X_1,X_2)\in \mathbb{P}^2: X_1^2+X_2^2-2X_1X_0=0\},$$
but I don't know how to parametrize it. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That affine curve "is" a circle of radius $1$ with center at $(1,0)$, so can be parametrized by 
$$ X = \cos \theta + 1 = \frac{2}{1+ t^2}\\
Y = \sin \theta = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2}$$ where $t = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$. So 
$$( 1\colon X\colon Y) = (1\colon \frac{2}{1+t^2} \colon \frac{2t}{1+t^2}) = (1+t^2\colon 2 \colon 2 t)$$
Let now homogenize $t = \frac{t_1}{t_0}$ and get 
$$(X_0 \colon X_1 \colon X_2) = (t_0^2 + t_1^2\colon 2 t_0^2 \colon 2 t_0 t_1) $$

The inverse map is given by two formulas 
$$(t_0 \colon t_1) = (X_1\colon X_2) = (X_2\colon 2X_0 -  X_1)$$

( you need two formulas ...)

Comment: I don't understand the last part

Comment: @mannav: I corrected the expressions ( a flip).

Comment: I don't understand why $(X_1:X_2)=(X_2:2X_0-X_1)$...

Comment: @mannav: because $X_2^2 = X_1( 2 X_0 - X_1)$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: All nonsingular plane conics are rational curves. If you make the linear change of coordinates $X_1'=X_1-X_0$ ($X_0'=X_0$, $X_2'=X_2$), you have the equation $X_1'^2 + X_2^2 = X_0^2$, which, in affine coordinates is the "circle" $x^2+y^2=1$. Have you learned how to parametrize that by rational functions?

Comment: As $(x,y)=(\frac{2t}{t^2+1},\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1})$, isn't it?